# How to access a server with domain name in ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh

How I can access a server with domain name  like 
 'ssh domainname\username@hostname'

Above one is not working? Please suggest correct syntax

Answer (score 4):

Either double the backslash or quote it:

```
ssh foo\\bar@example.com
ssh "foo\bar"@example.com
ssh 'foo\bar'@example.com
ssh "foo\bar@example.com"
ssh 'foo\bar@example.com'
```

Comment: This worked ssh foo\\bar@example.com